# GitHub how to test someone else's branch without overriding yours

Tags: git, github

I just have a question in mind when I'm using GitHub.

Say if person A who I'm working with made some changes to the master branch's file File B and want me to test it out before merging it. The problem is I edited some of the files too, and if I fetch his code it will override mine. How should I approach this if I want to test out his code without overriding mine. Should I just download the branch file and run that or is there a faster way without downloading his code?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are both working on the same branch?

Comment: Yea, we both working on a branch of the master branch to implement a function for our program.

Comment: do you know what branches for?

Comment: @Alexan be nice. Lol. Yes, you want to checkout person A's branch. If you can name their branch whatever you want. To create a tracking bench `git checkout -b branch_name_foo person_A_remote/branch_name`

Comment: "_we both working on a branch of the master branch_": So you created just **1** branch from master (say **branchA**), and then **both** of you are working on this same **branchA**?

Comment: @GinoMempin, as I understand they both used master branch

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your repo is under `/path/to/foo`.

```
cd /path/to/foo
git fetch origin master
git worktree add /path/to/bar FETCH_HEAD
```

The latest commit of `master` from the remote repository is checked out to `/path/to/bar`. You can test the code in `/path/to/bar`. The code includes A's changes, without yours. Later, you can just remove `/path/to/bar`, and run `git worktree prune` in `/path/to/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout the remote branch (after fetching), that won't touch your branch, no need to do anything fancier.

```
git checkout some-repo/some-branch
```

You will start working on `detached HEAD`, it's business as usual. The you can go back to your branch

```
git checkout my-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you and the person you are working with are on the *same branch* from the *same repo*, you could get the commit hash of your co-worker's changes, then checkout a detached HEAD from that commit.

See [`git checkout [--detach] <commit>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem--detachltcommitgt).

> Prepare to work on top of `<commit>`, by detaching HEAD at it (see
>   "DETACHED HEAD" section), and updating the index and the files in the
>   working tree. Local modifications to the files in the working tree are
>   kept, so that the resulting working tree will be the state recorded in
>   the commit plus the local modifications.

For example, if your co-worker pushed the commit with hash `9536809`:

```
git fetch             # to update your copy of remote repo
git checkout 9536809  # to get your co-worker's changes
```

You will then get a copy of the codes pushed by your co-worker at that specific commit. You can check the modifications and test it on your local env. Then when you are satisfied, you can just `git checkout` back to your *previous* branch.

```
git checkout <local-branch-name>

# OR

git checkout -
```

Note that part from the docs that doing this will also apply *your* local modifications. So before checking-out your co-worker's commit, either `commit` your changes first or [`stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) them first.

---

As a sidenote, it would have been better if you and your co-worker were working on *separate* branches, so that it would be easier to distinguish *your* work from *your co-worker's* work. Because eventually, you'll both need to sync up both of your changes on this same branch, before merging to master.